# How to add data files to build?

Tags: c#

I have an app which works with files. Now they are stored near the executable in bin/Debug. However, this directory is in .gitignore. So, if someone downloads my program from github, builds and runs it, these files would be missing and the program won't work. How can I make these files to be generated near an executable on build? My current thoughts is to exclude these file from gitignore using the '!' prefix. But I think there should be more "right" solution. Any ideas on how to do it better?

P. S. I am using Rider

Answer (score 0):

You can store the files in a subfolder in your solution then accessing them by using relative paths like this "../Test.txt"